# Tomcat j_security_check user ID

Tags: java, tomcat, j-security-check

Quick question for Tomcat j_security_check...

Anyone know how to change 'user_name' for 'id' in the user_role table, as I would prefer to 
validate by matching up the ID than a username

server.xml

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
        driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"
        connectionName="root" connectionPassword="password"
        userTable="user" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass"
        userRoleTable="user_role_link" roleNameCol="role_id" />
```

Tables

```
user
    id INT PK
    user_name PK
    user_pass
role
    id INT PK
    role_name
user_role
    user_id FK user_id to user.id
    role_id FK role_id to role.id
```

form is still:

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check" name="loginForm">        
    <j:if test='${not empty param["failed"]}'>
        Invalid sign-in credentials<br/>
    </j:if>        
    <h:inputText id="j_username" autocomplete="off" />
    <br/>
    <h:inputSecret id="j_password" autocomplete="off"/>
    <br/>
    <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Clear"/>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Login"/>          
</form>
```

I have got the role_id to work, but with user_id I just get a

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'user_name' in 'where clause'
```

exception

Thanks in advance

KPS

Comment: Replace `userNameCol="user_name"` by `userNameCol="id"`?

Comment: I thought about that, but just get the same 403 access denied & Exception but for 'id' instead of user_name.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that by `tomcat j_security_check`. If the `username` is a unique field it's the better solution to remove `id`. But I suggest you to merge these two tables. You can store only one table with these fields: `username`, `password` and, `role`. (or you can add `id` to it!)

I think in this way, your problem will be solved!